# What is an opaque type in Elm and why is it valuable?

Tags: elm

I've used types before but don't know what an opaque type is. I've seen it mentioned as well. Is it better to expose an opaque type than a type alias?

Answer (score 20):

Let’s answer this question by first looking at type aliases:

A type alias is fully transparent. This means that any other module importing it will have full access to its inner workings. Let’s say we’ve got a `User` module exposing a `User` type:

```
module User exposing User

type alias User =
    { userName : String
    , age : Int
    }
```

Anyone importing `User` can manipulate the data, e.g. `newUser = { oldUser | age = 25 }`. Or do `someUser = User "Bill"  27`. These manipulations are fine when you have control over the context that they exist in.

However, if `User` is part of a library then every change to the `User` type is a breaking change to people that use the library. For example, if an `email` field is added to `User`, then the constructor example (`someUser = User "Bill"  27`) will give a compiler error.

Even inside of a project codebase, a type alias can provide too much information to other modules which leads to code that is difficult to maintain and evolve. Perhaps a `User` changes drastically at some point and has a completely new set of properties. This would require changes wherever the code manipulates `User`s.

Opaque types are valuable because they avoid these issues. Here’s an opaque version of `User`:

```
module User exposing User

type User =
    User
        { userName : String
        , age : Int
        }
```

With this version, other modules cannot access or manipulate the data directly. Often, this means you will make and expose some getter and functions:

```
initUser : String -> Int -> User
userName : User -> String
age : User -> String
setAge : Int -> User -> User
```

This is more work, but it has advantages:

- Other modules only care about the `User` functions and don’t need to know what data is in the type
- The type can be updated without breaking code outside the containing module

---

Much of this explanation comes from [@wintvelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358807/wintvelt): [elmlang.slack.com](https://elmlang.slack.com/archives/design-patterns/p1480011953000265)

Comment: Here's some more discussion for authors of libraries and packages about the value: http://package.elm-lang.org/help/design-guidelines#keep-tags-and-record-constructors-secret

Comment: Thank for sharing this explanation. Because about half of it is an exact copy of an answer I posted earlier over on Slack ([here](https://elmlang.slack.com/archives/design-patterns/p1480011953000265)), a mention or link would have been nice.

Comment: Hey @wintvelt: Sorry! I thought it was a really good answer that would be helpful living in a more permanent place. I added a reference to your SO account. Maybe an SO mod could add you as an author?

Comment: Thanks for the mention. Appreciate it. Common practice in such cases is -  I think - to add at least a link to your source (link is already in my comment :).