# How to make a data structure which represents a subset of numbers?

Tags: types, elm

I was wondering if there's a way to make something like an `Int` type that can only represent a certain subset of numbers (like 0 ~ 29) and have the compiler throw an error if you try to do anything else with it.

I know I could do something like `type MoonPhaseDay = Day1|Day2| ... |Day29` but that doesn't scale over a larger range.

I'm trying to keep in mind the advice, "make impossible states impossible to represent". I could get by with an `Int` but I'm curious if there's a better way.

Comment: take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpDsk374LDE&t=2454s as Evan provides an example of something very similar

Answer (score 4):

What you're looking for is sometimes known as "Dependent Types", and is not part of Elm today.

However, you can get something similar by creating a type in it's own module, and instead of exporting the raw type constructor, only exporting a custom function that you provide (making it an "Opaque Type"). This way, that module contains the only code that has to be guarded.

---

[This answer by Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40794369/2014893) might be helpful when learning about Opaque types.

Comment: +1 I'd like to add that the "opaque type" i.e. not exporting the type constructor but rather a function that does some constraint checking, is also called a smart constructor. This might be helpful on further searches on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need to use a smart constructor. You enforce your constraints by controlling what you export from a module.

```
module Bounded exposing (Bounded, fromInt, toInt)


type Bounded
  = Bounded Int


fromInt : Int -> Maybe Bounded
fromInt n =
  if n < 0 || n > 29 then
    Nothing
  else
    Just (Bounded n)


toInt : Bounded -> Int
toInt (Bounded n) = n
```

### Explanation

The `Bounded` type is defined as a union type with one data constructor. When exporting the type we don't export the constructor, i.e. it's not part of the public API. This is known as an **opaque type**.

Users of the module can only ever create `Bounded` types using `fromInt`. `fromInt` is called a **smart constructor** because it has some logic (*the smarts*) to enforce the constraints.

If you need to work with the integer it wraps you use `toInt`. `toInt` is guaranteed to always return an integer between 0 and 29 inclusive. There's no hidden backdoor that would allow any other integer to be wrapped.

The HaskellWiki has a nice write up on [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors).

Finally, Richard Feldman in his talk "Types and Tests at The Gilded Rose" goes through a nice example [here](https://youtu.be/51O63Sb-Ae0?t=1310) that explains exactly what you want to do.